# Is there a library that integrates R into ruby?

Tags: ruby, r, windows-7, integration

I recently investigate a integration between ruby and R on Windows 7. So far, *rinruby* hangs (on my *Windows7* machine) when I run a script.  Now I learn from [this post](http://rubyforge.org/forum/message.php?msg_id=91848) that *rsruby* does not work on Windows at all. Does anybody know a library that would work?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer, but whatever it is it should be called 'uby'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me prefix this by saying that I am more of a Linux person than a Windows person ... but at some point the capabilities of the OSs do matter, as does their support for basic POSIX functionality etc.

Hence, it may not be a piece of cake to embed R into Ruby or link it on Windows, as handy as this may be for you.  R is after all dependent on the MinGW toolchain on Windows.

As an alternative, consider the excellent [Rserve](http://rforge.net/Rserve)---and I just noticed a seemingly new offspring [RserveWin](http://rforge.net/RserveWin/) Simon now also provides.  This merely needs to *run* somewhere, and you can then connect over tcp/ip. There are example clients for C/C++ and Java, and other projects such as for example [pyRserve](http://www.ralph-heinkel.com/pyRserve/index.html) and this [Rserve-Ruby-client](http://github.com/clbustos/Rserve-Ruby-client) which may fit the bill.

*Edit* One more Google search also leads to [this talk about R / Ruby integration](http://blog.chrislowis.co.uk/2009/02/15/LRUG-R-Ruby-talk.html) which refers to the [RSRruby gem](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rsruby/) but that (according to another quick search) seems to have issue on Windows too. Maybe Rserve and a connection really is your best ticket.

Comment: I think I will follow your advice and use a reserve as stand alone R server and call it from my program.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to run under JRuby then you may be able to use a Java-based bridge to R.

I currently use RSRuby to integrate R with a Rails application (running on OSX) but I am looking to switch to having a standalone R server shortly.